# Finding shortest path equation in product of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, parametrization

Suppose I have two metric spaces $(X, d)$ and $(Y, d')$.  Let $x_0, x_1 \in X$ and $y_0, y_1 \in Y$ arbitrarily.  Suppose $s(t) : I \to X$ parameterizes the shortest possible path from $x_0$ to $x_1$ in $X$ and $j(t) : I \to Y$ likewise parameterizes the shortest possible path from $y_0$ to $y_1$ in $Y$.

We get a [natural metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2773662/193876) $D : (X \times Y)^2 \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $$D : ((x, y), (x', y')) \mapsto \sqrt{ d(x, x')^2 + d'(y, y')^2 }$$
Intuitively, this makes me think we should also get a natural parameterization of the shortest possible path under $D$ from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$ in $X \times Y$ defined by
$$k : t \mapsto (s(t), j(t))$$
... but I don't really know how I would go about proving that this path is or is not optimal.  **What does a proof sketch look like for showing something like this?**  (I am happy to do the proof myself; I just don't know where to start and would like a point in the right direction.)  Thanks!

---

EDIT: Here is my progress toward a proof:

I think am correct, and can prove it as follows.

A [line](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/regs/linemetric.html) from $u$ to $v$ in a metric space $(U, d)$ is a set $\{ a \in U \mid d(u, a) + d(a, v) = d(u, v) \}$.

Since we assume $s$ is optimal, it follows that $s$ follows a segment of a line from $x_0$ to $x_1$.  Were this not the case, we could use the triangle inequality to find an at-least-as-good solution which does follow a segment of a line from $x_0$ to $x_1$.  So, assume $s$ follows a segment of a line from $x_0$ to $x_1$.  Apply this same logic to $j$ which goes from $y_0$ to $y_1$.

Let $k$ be as in the problem statement.  Then $k$ follows a line-segment from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$:

$$ \iff D((x_0, y_0), k(t)) + D(k(t), (x_1, y_1)) 
= D((x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1))$$

$$\iff D((x_0, y_0), (s(t), j(t))) + D((s(t), j(t)), (x_1, y_1)) = D((x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1))$$

$$\iff \sqrt{ d(x_0, s(t))^2 + d'(y_0, j(t))^2 } +
\sqrt{ d(s(t), x_1)^2 + d'(j(t), y_1)^2 } = 
\sqrt{ d(x_0, x_1)^2 + d'(y_0, y_1)^2 }$$

When I try to untangle this, the algebra is grotesque.  Is this actually the proof structure?  Just brute-forcing this despicable mess of algebra?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You have to do a lot of work to make this precise. 1. **Define** the length of path in an arbitrary metric space. 2. Not all paths wll have a finite length, thus introduce **rectifiable paths** which have finite length. 3. It is not clear whether shortest paths exist. 4. If $s, j$ are shortest paths, show that $k$ is rectifiable. 5. Show that it is the shortest path (I am not sure wheher this is true).

Comment: @PaulFrost I would think that path-connectedness is the only thing you need to guarantee the existence of a shortest path between arbitrary points in a metric space.  Is that correct?  (For my particular problem, which I generalized for this question, I can assume path-connectedness.)

Comment: No, consider the Euclidean plane minus the origin. What is the shortest path between (0,-1) and (0,1)?

Comment: Excellent counter-example, it's clearly been too long since I've looked at Munkres.  Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clean up the vagueness of the phrase "parameterizes the shortest possible path", then things become clearer.

The hypothesis you want is simply that the path $s(t) : [0,1] \to X$ is a *reparameterized geodesic*, meaning that $d(s(u),s(v))=|u-v| \cdot d(x_0,x_1)$ for all $u,v \in [0,1]$, and similarly for $j(t)$.

With that, it's then simple algebra to check that $k(t)$ is also a reparameterized geodesic.

By the way, n actual geodesic in this context would be a path of the form $s(t) : [0,d(x_0,x_1)] \to X$ such that $d(s(u),s(v)) = |u-v|$ for all $(u,v) \in [0,d(x_0,x_1)]$, and similarly for $j(t)$. But then the formula for $k$ would not make sense.

Comment: Thank you Lee!  As is often the case, the most useful thing here for me is the additional vocabulary - "reparameterized geodesic" is not a phrase I knew.  Now I'm equipped to find resources online and read up on the remaining subtleties.  As an aside, is my intuition that the metric-definition of a "line" is useful for discussing "shortest possible paths" in a metric space correct?  (I use this intuition in my edited answer in my partial attempt at a proof.)